# Connect to Oracle DB hosted on linux machine form windows machine with jdbc

Tags: java, linux, shell, jdbc, oracle11g

So I have this oracle database hosted on a Linux server.
I know how to access it using putty from a windows machine  but I need to access it using JDBC from a windows machine.
I have the hostname, port, service name, username and password for the database.
I don't understand how to open the connection.
I tried it like this:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname/servicename:port:xe",username,password);
```

but I am unable to connect. Please help

EDIT:

OK I realized that the address was wrong  so I changed it to this:
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:servicename",username,password);

now it gives the following error :
java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: The listened refused the connection with following error:
ORA-12505 TNS:Listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

Comment: And what happened (besides it didn't connect)? Did you get an error? If so, what was it? Also, the "@hostname/servicename" part. What did you put there?

Comment: it gave the following error
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
in the hostname and servicename part I put the machinename/servciename I cant tell you the actual ones.

Comment: `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "dbSchemaName/userName","password");` should be through.

Comment: Please see the changes in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your jdbc url in the format as this

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
```

Answer (score -2):

So I managed to correct it.
I had written

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:servicename",username,password);
```

the correct way to do it is

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/servicename",username,password);
```

as stated by knight rider.